# Aviso de data no aplicativo

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# no Visual Studio. Nessa aplicação existe uma tela que informa a quantidade de eventos que o usuário têm hoje, amanhã e depois de amanhã (quadro com cabeçalho verde).

Segue a tela:

[image: Software]

Preciso de um código que compare a data atual com a data cadastrada no banco de dados sobre o evento e envie a quantidade de eventos registrados para os dias futuros.

Ex.: No dia 05/08/2016 um usuário registrou um evento para hoje (08/08/2016) e esse evento foi analisado pelo código e a somatória dos eventos de hoje (08/08/2016) foi mandada para o `label.Text` e assim por diante.

Resumindo, o código deverá analisar os eventos por três dias e enviar a somatória de eventos pros três `label.Text`, dia atual, dia posterior e dia posterior ao dia posterior.

O código no qual faço consulta ao banco:

```
public DataTable Load(string sql)
{
    DALTexto objSqlCeServerDAL = DALTexto.GetInstance(connString); 
    objSqlCeServerDAL.Open();
    SqlCeDataAdapter dAd = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, objSqlCeConnection);
    dAd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        dAd.Fill(dSet, "textos");
        return dSet.Tables["textos"];
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        dSet.Dispose();
        dAd.Dispose();
        objSqlCeServerDAL.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: O que você já tentou ?

Comment: @stringnome eu tentei o método DataTable, mas faltou alguma parte se não me engano, assim não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Tente ser mais específico. Como é feita a consulta de dados no banco? Você usa algum ORM? Já tentou algo? De pouco vale a imagem que você postou, tente [edit] sua pergunta e melhorá-la um pouco, adicionar suas tentativas e informações relevantes...

Comment: @jbueno Adicionei detalhes

Comment: Marlon, tente usar ao inves de datatable, algo como Dictionary, ou melhor uma List, pois são objetos altamente tipados, e que você consegue acessa-los diretamente com um índice, para acessar um dado do datatable você vai precisar usar um DataReader.

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo?